# using bytearray with socket.recv_into

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, arrays

I am doing some socket IO, and using a bytearray object as a buffer. I would like to receive data with an offset into this buffer using csock.recv_into  as shown below in order to avoid creating intermediary string objects. Unfortunately, it seems bytearrays can't be used this way, and the code below doesn't work.

```
buf    = bytearray(b" " * toread)
read   = 0
while(toread):
  nbytes = csock.recv_into(buf[read:],toread)
  toread -= nbytes
  read   += nbytes
```

So instead I am using the code below, which *does* use a temporary string (and works)...

```
buf    = bytearray(b" " * toread)
read   = 0
while(toread):
  tmp = csock.recv(toread)
  nbytes = len(tmp)
  buf[read:] = tmp
  toread -= nbytes
  read   += nbytes
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this that doesn't require copying intermediate strings around?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What version of Python are you using (exactly)? http://bugs.python.org/issue7827 suggests that this is fixed as of Python 2.7.2.

Comment: python version is 2.7.3. And this is not related to that bug... csock.recv_into(buf) works just fine for me. What's not possible is to use it like this: csock.recv_into(buf[read:]) as then the original buf object doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a `memoryview` to wrap your `bytearray`:

```
buf = bytearray(toread)
view = memoryview(buf)
while toread:
    nbytes = sock.recv_into(view, toread)
    view = view[nbytes:] # slicing views is cheap
    toread -= nbytes
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Didn't know about memoryviews... Reading up on them now!