# Reusing Python Bytearray/Memoryview

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am attempting to receive a series of protobufs via a socket; I won't know the amount of data in advance. I'm sending a fair amount of them, and need to [buffer the messages](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/length-prefix-framing-for-protocol-buffers/) as I receive them (to ensure that I get all messages). I would like to make use of the bytearray/memoryview available in Python to eliminate an unnecessary copy.

I'm currently using a string and appending the data as I receive it. This is easy and I can "shift" down the "buffer" by doing something like:

```
# Create the buffer
str_buffer = []

# Get some data and add it to our "buffer"
str_buffer += "Hello World"

# Do something with the data . . .

# "shift"/offset the message by the data we processed
str_buffer = str_buffer[6:]
```

Is it possible to do something similar using a bytearray/memoryview?

```
# Create the buffer/memoryarray 
buffer = bytearray(1024)
view   = memoryview(buffer)

# I can set a single byte
view[0] = 'a'

# I can "offset" the view by the data we processed, but doing this 
# shrinks the view by 3 bytes. Doing this multiple times eventually shrinks
# the view to 0.
view = view[3:]
```

The problem arises when I try to add more data to the end. If I ever "offset" the existing view, the size of the view "shrinks*" and I can add less and less data. Is there anyway to reuse the existing memoryview and just shift the data to the left?

*Based on the documentation, I know I can't resize the array. I think the illusion of shrinking is a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using bytearray with socket.recv\_into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962119/using-bytearray-with-socket-recv-into)

Comment: I already found that post. The answer presupposes that the amount of data is known in advance. As such, you can allocate the appropriate size bytearray before you start receiving data. It mentions nothing of reusing a (smallish) fixed size bytearray/memoryview.

Comment: You don't need to know in advance how much data the sender will send to use `recv_from()`.  it always returns the number of bytes it got; if that's the size of your `memoryview`, then theres more data to be had, call `recv_from()` again.

Comment: In the example you mentioned `toread` is defined outside of the while loop. The `recv_into` returns the amount of data read, yes. The amount of data is subtracted from `toread` until it is 0. This seems to indicate that the amount of data `toread` is known in advance, used to create the appropriate sized bytearray. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you really, honestly don't need to know in advance how much data to expect, just keep reading until you don't get any more data:

```
import socket, sys

HOST = 'localhost'        # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server

recvbuff = bytearray(16)
recvview = memoryview(recvbuff)

size = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    nbytes = s.recv_into(recvview)
    if not nbytes:
        break
    size += nbytes
    recvview = recvview[nbytes:]
    if not len(recvview):
        print "filled a chunk", recvbuff
        recvview = memoryview(recvbuff)

print 'end of data', recvbuff[:len(recvview)], size

s.close()
```

Comment: Fantastic! This helped out a lot, so thank you for that. I'd like to add that I was able to "shift" the data in the memoryview by `b = bytearray(view[2:]).extend('\0' * 2)` (shift left by 2) and then `v = memoryview(b)`. It seems to work, though I don't know yet if it's the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: er... i thought you wanted to avoid doing copies.  `bytearray.extend` will copy its contents to the newly allocated array...

Comment: Argh, I do... I'm working on the data as I receive it. I guess my question is if I have a buffer: `[a][b][c][ ][ ]` and I do work on `a` how do I shift the buffer `[b][c][ ][ ][ ]` and still add to the end: `[b][c][d][ ][ ]`. When I tested the code you gave, it seemed to fill the buffer then clear it?

Comment: um... well, either you want to copy data around or not; you can certainly copy `recvbuff[:len(recvview)] = recvview` easy enough, but I would not do that (just use plain ol' `recv` if you want to make copies like this).  Why do you think you need it?